# Overlaying actual data on a boxplot from a pandas dataframe

Tags: matplotlib, pandas, dataframe, boxplot, seaborn

I am using Seaborn to make boxplots from pandas dataframes. `Seaborn` boxplots seem to essentially read the dataframes the same way as the `pandas` `boxplot` functionality (so I hope the solution is the same for both -- but I can just use the `dataframe.boxplot` function as well). My dataframe has 12 columns and the following code generates a single plot with one boxplot for each column (just like the `dataframe.boxplot()` function would).

```
fig, ax = plt.subplots()
sns.set_style("darkgrid", {"axes.facecolor":"darkgrey"})
pal = sns.color_palette("husl",12)
sns.boxplot(dataframe, color = pal)
```

Can anyone suggest a simple way of overlaying all the values (by columns) while making a boxplot from dataframes? 
I will appreciate any help with this.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A general solution for the boxplot for the entire dataframe, which should work for both `seaborn` and `pandas` as their are all `matplotlib` based under the hood, I will use `pandas` plot as the example, assuming `import matplotlib.pyplot as plt` already in place. As you have already have the `ax`, it would make better sense to just use `ax.text(...)` instead of `plt.text(...)`.

```
In [35]:    
print df
         V1        V2        V3        V4        V5
0  0.895739  0.850580  0.307908  0.917853  0.047017
1  0.931968  0.284934  0.335696  0.153758  0.898149
2  0.405657  0.472525  0.958116  0.859716  0.067340
3  0.843003  0.224331  0.301219  0.000170  0.229840
4  0.634489  0.905062  0.857495  0.246697  0.983037
5  0.573692  0.951600  0.023633  0.292816  0.243963

[6 rows x 5 columns]

In [34]:    
df.boxplot()
for x, y, s in zip(np.repeat(np.arange(df.shape[1])+1, df.shape[0]), 
                   df.values.ravel(), df.values.astype('|S5').ravel()):
    plt.text(x,y,s,ha='center',va='center')
```

[image]

For a single series in the dataframe, a few small changes is necessary:

```
In [35]:    
sub_df=df.V1
pd.DataFrame(sub_df).boxplot()
for x, y, s in zip(np.repeat(1, df.shape[0]), 
                   sub_df.ravel(), sub_df.values.astype('|S5').ravel()):
    plt.text(x,y,s,ha='center',va='center')
```

[image]

Making scatter plots is also similar:

```
#for the whole thing
df.boxplot()
plt.scatter(np.repeat(np.arange(df.shape[1])+1, df.shape[0]), df.values.ravel(), marker='+', alpha=0.5)
#for just one column
sub_df=df.V1
pd.DataFrame(sub_df).boxplot()
plt.scatter(np.repeat(1, df.shape[0]), sub_df.ravel(), marker='+', alpha=0.5)
```

[image]
[image]

To overlay stuff on `boxplot`, we need to first guess where each boxes are plotted at among `xaxis`. They appears to be at `1,2,3,4,....`. Therefore, for the values in the first column, we want them to be plot at x=1; the 2nd column at x=2 and so on.

Any efficient way of doing it is to use `np.repeat`, repeat `1,2,3,4...`, each for `n` times, where `n` is the number of observations. Then we can make a plot, using those numbers as `x` coordinates. Since it is one-dimensional, for the `y` coordinates, we will need a flatten view of the data, provided by `df.ravel()`

For overlaying the text strings, we need a anther step (a loop). As we can only plot one x value, one y value and one text string at a time.

Comment: I am sorry, the phrase "actual values" is confusing. By that I meant a sort of scatter plot overlayed on the boxplot - i.e. with dots in place of the numeric values. Thanks for looking at my question!

Comment: Yeah, that one is confusing. See edit. I will suggest you use a reasonable `alpha` value so that if you have a lot of data point you can see the 'cloud' better. If you want to look fancy, consider this http://nbviewer.ipython.org/github/mgymrek/pybeeswarm/blob/master/beeswarm_example.ipynb?create=1

Comment: Yeah, that is fancy. Thanks for the quick response, @CT Zhu! That worked like a charm. I have to admit, I will have to stare at the solution some more to understand what you did there..  I need a couple more points to give you an upvote.

Comment: No problem, I've since written a few more lines of code, this time in  `English` language for you to stare at. Cheers!

Comment: @CTZhu I want to do something very similar to this however I am using dataframe.boxplot(by='column1') this grouping doesn't seem to work with your example. do you have any suggestions to this. essentually my box plot is xaxis df[column1], yaxis df[column2] and I would like to plot the scatter plot on top of it. but with the xticks set to texts i am confused. I was able to find the xticks and xtick_labels which the boxplot set.

Answer (score 6):

This hasn't been added to the `seaborn.boxplot` function yet, but there's something similar in the [`seaborn.violinplot`](http://stanford.edu/~mwaskom/software/seaborn/examples/violinplots.html) function, which has [other advantages](http://stanford.edu/~mwaskom/software/seaborn/tutorial/plotting_distributions.html#comparing-distributions-boxplot-and-violinplot):

```
x = np.random.randn(30, 6)
sns.violinplot(x, inner="points")
sns.despine(trim=True)
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

I have the following trick:

```
data = np.random.randn(6,5)

df = pd.DataFrame(data,columns = list('ABCDE'))

Now assign a dummy column to df:
df['Group'] = 'A'

print df

          A         B         C         D         E Group
0  0.590600  0.226287  1.552091 -1.722084  0.459262     A
1  0.369391 -0.037151  0.136172 -0.772484  1.143328     A
2  1.147314 -0.883715 -0.444182 -1.294227  1.503786     A
3 -0.721351  0.358747  0.323395  0.165267 -1.412939     A
4 -1.757362 -0.271141  0.881554  1.229962  2.526487     A
5 -0.006882  1.503691  0.587047  0.142334  0.516781     A
```

Use the `df.groupby.boxplot()`, you get it done.

```
df.groupby('Group').boxplot()
```

[image: Box plot overlay]